# Top 10 editors partitioned by year

Tags: sql, stackexchange, t-sql

I wanted to get some stats on who has done the most edits on Code Review, so I wrote [the following query on SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/463202/top-10-editors-partitioned-by-year). All improvement suggestions are welcome.

Note that I used a cursor to partition top users by year because at first there was a fundamental flaw in my logic trying to get the top users overall and then grouping them by years, which gave incorrect results.

The execution plan doesn't look too bad, considering the cursor only iterates a total of 6 times (2011-2016), but if it can be improved without degrading readability too much, I'd like to know.

```
/*
  Aggregate the top 10 users with the most post edits 
  for each year, along with relevant statistics.
*/

/* Filter for Edit events: */
declare @EditPostHistoryTypes table (Id int);
insert into @EditPostHistoryTypes
    select Id 
    from PostHistoryTypes 
    where Name like 'Edit%';

/* All edits on record: */
declare @CountAllEdits int = (
    select count(Id) 
    from PostHistory
    where 
      PostHistoryTypeId in (select Id from @EditPostHistoryTypes)
      and PostId in (
          select Id from Posts 
          where DeletionDate is null
      )
);
/* Hold top editors per year for main query: */
declare @TopEditorsPerYear table (
    [Year] int, 
    UserId int, 
    CountByYear int,
    TotalCount int
);
/* Get all years with edit activity: */
declare _years cursor for
    select distinct datepart(year, CreationDate)
    from PostHistory
    where PostHistoryTypeId in (
        select Id 
        from PostHistoryTypes 
        where Name like 'Edit%'
    );
declare @currentYear int;
/* Cursor to split top editors into yearly partitions: */
open _years;
fetch next from _years into @currentYear;
while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin;
    insert into @TopEditorsPerYear ([Year], UserId, CountByYear, TotalCount)
        select top 10
            datepart(year, ph.CreationDate) as [Year],
            ph.UserId,
            count(ph.Id),
            (select count(Id) from PostHistory as phInline where phInline.UserId = ph.UserId)
        from PostHistory as ph
        where PostHistoryTypeId in (
            select Id 
            from PostHistoryTypes 
            where Name like 'Edit%'
        )
        and datepart(year, CreationDate) = @currentYear
        and UserId is not null
        group by 
            datepart(year, CreationDate), 
            UserId
        order by count(Id) desc;
    fetch next from _years into @currentYear;
end;
/* Cleanup cursor: */
close _years;
deallocate _years;

/* Main query: */
select
    [Year Rank] = row_number() over (
        partition by tops.[Year]
        order by tops.CountByYear desc
    ),
    [Year] = tops.[Year],
    [User Link] = hist.UserId,
    [Annual Total] = tops.CountByYear,
    [% Year/User] = cast((cast(tops.CountByYear as decimal(10,2)) / tops.TotalCount) * 100 as decimal(5,2)),
    [% Year/Site] = cast((cast(tops.CountByYear as decimal(10,2)) / @CountAllEdits) * 100 as decimal(5,2)),
    [% Total/Site] = cast((cast(tops.TotalCount as decimal(10,2)) / @CountAllEdits) * 100 as decimal(5,2)),
    [Grand Total] = tops.TotalCount
from 
    PostHistory as hist
    join @TopEditorsPerYear as tops on hist.UserId = tops.UserId
where 
    PostHistoryTypeId in (select Id from @EditPostHistoryTypes)
    and PostId in (select Id from Posts where DeletionDate is null)
group by 
    hist.UserId, 
    tops.[Year], 
    tops.CountByYear, 
    tops.TotalCount
order by 
    [Year Rank] asc, 
    [Year] asc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simplified down to a [single query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/468230/top-10-editors-partitioned-by-year) :-)

You calculate COUNTs using different WHERE-conditions and aggregation levels, but the base tables are always the same:

- CountByYear: Edits per user & year
- TotalCount: All actions of a user
- CountAllEdits: All Edits of all users (including UserId NULL)

In a case like this you can utilize *conditional counts* (`COUNT(CASE...)`) and *Windowed Aggregate Functions* (`SUM() OVER`).

To be able to calculate both *Edits only* and *All actions* I use a `LEFT JOIN PostHistoryTypes ON Name like 'Edit%'` which returns `NULL` for non-edit-actions. This enables both counts using:

```
count(PostHistory.PostHistoryTypeId) = all actions 
count(PostHistoryTypes.id)           = edits only
```

Aggregation starts with the lowest level, `GROUP BY UserId, YEAR`. And because `OVER` is processed *after*  aggregation you get the higher aggregation levels using:

```
sum(count(...)) over (partition by UserId) = -- count by user
sum(count(...)) over ()                    = -- count all
```

This results in this base query:

```
   select
      [Year Rank] = row_number() 
                    over (partition by datepart(year, CreationDate)
                                         -- (excluding NULL UserId)
                          order by count(case when UserId is not null then PHT.Id end) desc),
      [Year] = datepart(year, CreationDate),
      UserId,
      CountByYear = count(pht.id), -- Edits per user & year
      TotalCount = sum(count(UserId)) over (partition by UserId), -- All actions of a user
      CountAllEdits = sum(count(pht.Id)) over () -- All Edits (including NULL UserId)
   from 
       PostHistory as ph
   left join PostHistoryTypes as pht
     on ph.PostHistoryTypeId = pht.Id
    and pht.Name like 'Edit%'
   where PostId in (select Id from Posts where DeletionDate is null)
   group by 
       [UserId], 
       datepart(year, CreationDate)
```

And then you just have to filter for the top 10 and do the percentage calculations:

```
/*
  Aggregate the top 10 users with the most post edits 
  for each year, along with relevant statistics.
*/

with cte as 
 (
   select
      [Year Rank] = row_number() 
                    over (partition by datepart(year, CreationDate)
                                         -- (excluding NULL UserId)
                          order by count(case when UserId is not null then PHT.Id end) desc),
      [Year] = datepart(year, CreationDate),
      UserId,
      CountByYear = count(pht.id), -- Edits per user & year
      TotalCount = sum(count(UserId)) over (partition by UserId), -- All actions of a user
      CountAllEdits = sum(count(pht.Id)) over () -- All Edits (including NULL UserId)
   from 
       PostHistory as ph
   left join PostHistoryTypes as pht
     on ph.PostHistoryTypeId = pht.Id
    and pht.Name like 'Edit%'
   where PostId in (select Id from Posts where DeletionDate is null)
   group by 
       [UserId], 
       datepart(year, CreationDate)
 )
select
   [Year Rank],
   [Year],
   [User Link] = UserId,

   -- number of edits by user & year
   -- [Edits by User & Year]?
   [Annual Total] = CountByYear,

   -- % of edits vs. all actions by user & year
   [% Year/User]  = cast(100.00 * CountByYear / TotalCount    as decimal(5,2)),

   -- % of edits by user & year vs. all edits 
   [% Year/Site]  = cast(100.00 * CountByYear / CountAllEdits as decimal(5,2)),

   -- % of actions by user vs. all edits 
   [% Total/Site] = cast(100.00 * TotalCount  / CountAllEdits as decimal(5,2)),

   -- number of all actions by user
   [Grand Total] = TotalCount

from cte
where [Year Rank] <= 10
  and CountByYear > 0
order by 
    [Year Rank] asc, 
    [Year] asc;
;
```

I noticed you didn't use exactly the same WHERE-conditions all the time, in your `TotalCount` calculation you didn't check for `DeletionDate is null`, but in fact there's no NULL at all in that column (thus it could be removed from the query).

It was hard for me to infer the actual meaning from the column names.
And the calculation of [% Total/Site] doesn't make sense for me, you compare all actions of a user to all edit-actions.

First I would expect indicators like:

- edit count of this user (per year & globally)
- % edits of this user vs all edits (per year & globally)

And additionally maybe:

- all actions count of this user (per year & globally)
- % edits vs all actions of this user (per year & globally)

Comment: Wow. Mind blown. Very nice ;-)